# How to get Java Enum from C++ JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm creating a simple C++ wrapper through Java JNI to access my Java code. My question is, I have enumeration in my Java code that I need to get the value from my C++ JNI code. What is the best way to do it?

Here is my snapshot of my Java code :

```
package mypackage;

    public class ClassFooJava
    {   
        public enum MyEnum
        {
            Enabled    (0),
            DoNothing  (1),
            Disable    (2)
            ;

            public int getValue()
            {
                return valueEnum;
            }

            private final int valueEnum;

            private MyEnum(int valueEnum)
            {
                this.valueEnum = valueEnum;
            }
        }

        static 
        {
            try
            {
                System.load("MyCPlusPlus.dll");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Caught exception: " + e.toString());

            }       
        }
        public native long GetInstance();
        public native void FreeInstance(long LearningAccess);
        public native int FooFunctionJava(MyEnum myEnum);
    }
```

And here is my snapshot of my C++ code :

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_cummins_ctp_ClassFooJava
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,
          jobject j_myEnum)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

    jfieldID myEnumField = env->GetFieldID(cls, "MyEnum",  "Lmypackage.ClassFooJava;");

    if (myEnumField == NULL)
    {
        // IT ALWAYS NULL
        cout << "NULL NULL NULL" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Notice that in my C++ code, the enumField is always null.
What is wrong with my code? Is my code doing the right thing to get the enumeration field within the object? Should I create the enumeration outside my ClassFooJava class?
I do really appreciate any help.

Comment: `MyEnum` is an enum type, not a field. A field would be if you had something like `private MyEnum myEnum;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is wrong with my code?

```
Java_com_cummins_ctp_ClassFooJava
```

The name of the function you are implementing is missing.

> Is my code doing the right thing to get the enumeration field within the object?

You are passing in the `MyEnum` as an argument. It is `j_myEnum`. Perhaps you wanted the `valueEnum`

```
jfieldID valueEnumField = 
                     env->GetFieldID(cls, "valueEnum", "Lmypackage/ClassFooJava$MyEnum;");
```

> Should I create the enumeration outside my ClassFooJava class?

That's up to you.

Comment: Hi Peter, I could not get it work.. Probably this line is still not correct : env->GetFieldID(cls, "valueEnum", "Lmypackage/ClassFooJava$MyEnum;");  But anyway, it works if I put the enumeration outside my ClassFooJava. So I treat the enum as separate 'class' in my JNI C++ code. And it works.